# Executable python script using CMD commands doesn't work

Tags: python, button, cmd, command, executable

So I wrote a script which handles cmd commands and works almost perfectly when I run it (it freezes sometimes but that's another topic) but when I make an executable of it in cmd with

```
pyinstaller --onefile myscript.py
```

or

```
pyinstaller --onefile --windowed myscript.py
```

and I run the exe and click on any button it just opens another instance of the program but doesn't execute the command. As I said before, when I run it as a script it works fine so I don't understand the problem.Anyone?

The code (sorry the words are in my language):

```
import os
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.font as font


#os.system('cmd /k "shutdown /s /t time"'))

def visszavon():
    os.system('cmd /k "shutdown /a"')


def felora():
    os.system('cmd /k "shutdown /s /t 1800"')


def egyora():
    os.system('cmd /k "shutdown /s /t 3600"')


def masfel():
    os.system('cmd /k "shutdown /s /t 5400"')


def ketora():
    os.system('cmd /k "shutdown /s /t 7200"')



root=Tk()
root.geometry('400x200')
root.configure(bg='#2c2f33')

#szöveg
szv=Label(root,text='Shutdown',fg='#1ABB94',bg='#2c2f33')
szv.place(y=0,x=145)
szv.configure(font=("Courier New", 20))

#felora
felo=Button(root,text='30 perc',fg='#1ABB94',bg='#2c2f33',bd=0.5,command=felora)
felo.place(x=20,y=60,height=40,width=75)
felo.configure(font=("Courier New", 10))

#1 óra
egyo=Button(root,text='60 perc',fg='#1ABB94',bg='#2c2f33',bd=0.5,command=egyora)
egyo.place(x=115,y=60,height=40,width=75)
egyo.configure(font=("Courier New", 10))


#1,5óra
masfo=Button(root,text='90 perc',fg='#1ABB94',bg='#2c2f33',bd=0.5,command=masfel)
masfo.place(x=210,y=60,height=40,width=75)
masfo.configure(font=("Courier New", 10))

#2 óra
keto=Button(root,text='120 perc',fg='#1ABB94',bg='#2c2f33',bd=0.5,command=ketora)
keto.place(x=305,y=60,height=40,width=75)
keto.configure(font=("Courier New", 10))

#cancel
canc=Button(root,text='Visszavonás',fg='#1ABB94',bg='#2c2f33',bd=0.5,command=visszavon)
canc.place(x=162.5,y=130,height=40,width=75)
canc.configure(font=("Courier New", 8))


root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I don't think you need cmd /k for this. Just run `subprocess.check_call(["shutdown","/a"])` os.system is deprecated and composing your own command line often leads to command not running

Comment: When I use it I get: Command '['shutdown', '/a']' returned non-zero exit status 1116. What can be the problem?

Comment: maybe you need elevated privileges for `shutdown` that you had with python but not with the new executable? you could try with a command that doesn't require elevated privileges (like calc or notepas)

Comment: I tried it with calc and it works so yes it might be the privileges but how could i solve that?

Comment: Type `net helpmsg 1116` and read the description.

`Unable to abort the system shutdown because no shutdown was in progress.`. Programmers don't type user commands. They program see https://pypi.org/project/WMI/

Comment: You can’t write a script which shuts down the pc with this wmi module(imo).